# How to avoid data collision when Kafka consumer loses connectivity with Kafka while still active and gets replaced by another consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, parallel-processing, race-condition

We have a solution where producer sends data to multiple partitions of Kafka topic, and messages belonging to a particular user always end up in the same partition (message key partitioning). We need data belonging to the same user to be processed strictly sequentially on the consumer end.

However there can be a situation where the consumer A consuming from partition 1 is losing connectivity to Kafka, and Kafka decides that it lost consumer A and re-assigns partition 1 to consumer B.

Consumer A can still be active and processing user X's data. At the same time consumer B picks up next message from partition 1 and it turns out to be another portion of data related to user X. In this transitional case we get two consumers processing the data of the same user in parallel and there is a possibility of race condition.

Similar issue is when we add new consumer to scale up, in this case two consumers may be processing data messages for the same user over transitional period upon rebalancing. Static group membership will not help in this case.

How can we avoid such collisions in a transitional situation of consumers re-arrangement for partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consumer code should catch a `WakeupException` while polling and immediately stop processing any data it had seen, before the group rebalances.

Beyond that, you could implement distributed locking, but Kafka doesn't provide this feature itself. You could use Zookeeper for that, however.